# Transaction error on betting

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, metamask, ganache

I am following this tutorial to make a betting App. I want to setup in my local environment with ganache. I didn't take the ropsten network approach as shown in tutorial

**Tutorial:** https://medium.com/coinmonks/tutorial-create-a-sports-betting-dapp-on-the-ethereum-blockchain-part-2-cd4753afe702

*The error I get when I place bet*

[image]

**My truffle-config.js**

```
// var WalletProvider = require("truffle-wallet-provider");
// const Wallet = require('ethereumjs-wallet');
// var ropstenPrivateKey = new Buffer("xyz","hex");
// var ropstenWallet = Wallet.fromPrivateKey(ropstenPrivateKey);
// var ropstenProvider = new WalletProvider(ropstenWallet, "https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/zxzy");

module.exports = {
  // See <http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration>
  // to customize your Truffle configuration!
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*", // Match any network id
    },
    // ropsten: {
    //   provider: ropstenProvider,
    //   gas: 4600000,
    //   network_id: 3
    // },
compilers: {
      solc: {
        version: "^0.5.16",
        optimizer: {
          enabled: true,
          runs: 200
      }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

But my balance changes are reflected both in meta mask and in ganache every time I click on bet

[image: Balance deducted on every call]

Also my meta mask popup doesn't come up whenever any kind of transaction is invoked

I connected my meta mask with the private key of ganache account successfully that is shown in image above but there is no popup whenever I do any kind of transaction

This is my Contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.16;


contract Betting {
   address public owner;
   uint256 public minimumBet;
   uint256 public totalBetsOne;
   uint256 public totalBetsTwo;
   address payable[] public players;
   struct Player {
      uint256 amountBet;
      uint16 teamSelected;
    }
// The address of the player and => the user info
   mapping(address => Player) public playerInfo;
   function() external payable {}
 constructor() public {
      owner = msg.sender;
      minimumBet = 100000000000000;
      totalBetsTwo = 30;
      totalBetsOne = 20;
    }
function kill() public {
      if(msg.sender == owner) selfdestruct(msg.sender);
    }
function checkPlayerExists(address player) public view returns(bool){
      for(uint256 i = 0; i < players.length; i++){
         if(players[i] == player) return true;
      }
      return false;
    }


    function bet(uint8 _teamSelected) public payable {
      //The first require is used to check if the player already exist
      require(!checkPlayerExists(msg.sender));
      //The second one is used to see if the value sended by the player is
      //Higher than the minimum value
      require(msg.value >= minimumBet);

      //We set the player informations : amount of the bet and selected team
      playerInfo[msg.sender].amountBet = msg.value;
      playerInfo[msg.sender].teamSelected = _teamSelected;

      //then we add the address of the player to the players array
      players.push(msg.sender);

      //at the end, we increment the stakes of the team selected with the player bet
      if ( _teamSelected == 1){
          totalBetsOne += msg.value;
      }
      else{
          totalBetsTwo += msg.value;
      }
    }
    // Generates a number between 1 and 10 that will be the winner
    function distributePrizes(uint16 teamWinner) public {
      address payable[1000] memory winners;
      //We have to create a temporary in memory array with fixed size
      //Let's choose 1000
      uint256 count = 0; // This is the count for the array of winners
      uint256 LoserBet = 0; //This will take the value of all losers bet
      uint256 WinnerBet = 0; //This will take the value of all winners bet
        address  payable playerAddress;
      //We loop through the player array to check who selected the winner team
      for(uint256 i = 0; i < players.length; i++){
           playerAddress = players[i];

         //If the player selected the winner team
         //We add his address to the winners array
         if(playerInfo[playerAddress].teamSelected == teamWinner){
            winners[count] = playerAddress;
            count++;
         }
      }

      //We define which bet sum is the Loser one and which one is the winner
      if ( teamWinner == 1){
         LoserBet = totalBetsTwo;
         WinnerBet = totalBetsOne;
      }
      else{
          LoserBet = totalBetsOne;
          WinnerBet = totalBetsTwo;
      }


      //We loop through the array of winners, to give ethers to the winners
      for(uint256 j = 0; j < count; j++){
          // Check that the address in this fixed array is not empty
         if(winners[j] != address(0)){
            address add = winners[j];
            uint256 betwa = playerInfo[add].amountBet;
            //Transfer the money to the user
            winners[j].transfer( (betwa*(10000+(LoserBet*10000/WinnerBet)))/10000 );
            }
      }
      delete playerInfo[playerAddress]; // Delete all the players
      players.length = 0; // Delete all the players array
      LoserBet = 0; //reinitialize the bets
      WinnerBet = 0;
      totalBetsOne = 0;
      totalBetsTwo = 0;
    }

    function AmountOne() public view returns(uint256){
       return totalBetsOne;
    }

    function AmountTwo() public view returns(uint256){
       return totalBetsTwo;
    }
}
```

**This is my web3 file**

```
import Web3 from 'web3'

let getWeb3 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  // Wait for loading completion before loading web3, to be sure it's
  // already injected
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var results
    var web3 = window.web3
    // Checking if Web3 has been injected by the browser MetaMask
    if (typeof web3 === 'undefined') {
      // Use MetaMask's provider.
      web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider)

      results = {
        web3: web3
      }
      console.log('Injected web3 detected.' , results);
      resolve(results)
    } else {
      // If no web3 is detected, then the local web3 provider is loaded.
      var provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://127.0.0.1:7545')
      web3 = new Web3(provider)
      results = {
        web3: web3
      }
      console.log('No web3 instance injected, using Local web3.');
      resolve(results)
    }
  })
})

export default getWeb3
```

I have spent along time on it still stuck at this position any guesses where I am wrong

These are my app.js and components

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import getWeb3 from './utils/getWeb3.js';
// import {Grid,Row,Col} from 'react-bootstrap';
import TeamA from './TeamA.jsx';
import TeamB from './TeamB.jsx';
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super(); //This is needed in every constructor to allow the use of 'this'
//We define the two variables we need in the state of our component, so they can be updated
    this.state = {
      web3 : '',
      address: '',
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    getWeb3.then(results => {
      /*After getting web3, we save the informations of the web3 user by
      editing the state variables of the component */
      
      results.web3.eth.getAccounts( (error,acc) => {
        //this.setState is used to edit the state variables
      
        
        this.setState({
          address: acc[0],
          web3: results.web3
        })
      });
    }).catch( () => {
      //If no web3 provider was found, log it in the console
      console.log('Error finding web3.')
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
<header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Bet-eth</h1>
        </header>
        <div>
          Welcome on my Ethereum Betting website <br/>
        Your Wallet address is {this.state.address}
        </div>
        {/*We define a grid*/}
        <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-6"><TeamA/></div>
        <div className="col-md-6"><TeamB/></div>
        
       
        
        </div>
</div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

**TeamA component**

```
import React from 'react';
// import {Grid,Row,Col} from 'react-bootstrap';
import getWeb3 from './utils/getWeb3.js';
import BettingContract from './contracts/Betting.json';
import './App.css';



class TeamA extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
      web3: '',
      Amount: '',
      InputAmount: '',
      weiConversion : 1000000000000000000
    }

    this.getAmount = this.getAmount.bind(this);
    this.Bet = this.Bet.bind(this);
    this.MakeWin = this.MakeWin.bind(this);
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    getWeb3.then(results => {
      /*After getting web3, we save the informations of the web3 user by
      editing the state variables of the component */
      results.web3.eth.getAccounts( (error,acc) => {
        //this.setState is used to edit the state variables
        
        this.setState({
          web3: results.web3
        })
      });
      //At the end of the first promise, we return the loaded web3
      return results.web3
    }).then(results => {
      //In the next promise, we pass web3 (in results) to the getAmount function
      this.getAmount(results)
    }).catch( () => {
      //If no web3 provider was found, log it in the console
      console.log('Error finding web3.')
    })
  }



  getAmount(web3){
    //Get the contract
    const contract = require('truffle-contract');
    
    const Betting = contract(BettingContract);
    Betting.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);
    var BettingInstance;
    web3.eth.getAccounts((error, accounts) => {
    Betting.deployed().then((instance) => {

      //Instantiate the contract in a promise
      BettingInstance = instance

    }).then((result) => {
      //Calling the AmountOne function of the smart-contract
      
      return BettingInstance.AmountOne.call({from: accounts[0]})
    }).then((result) => {
      //Then the value returned is stored in the Amount state var.
      //Divided by 10000 to convert in ether.
      
      this.setState({
        Amount : result.words[0] / 10000
      })
    });
  })
  }

  handleInputChange(e) {
    this.setState({InputAmount: e.target.value*this.state.weiConversion});
    console.log(this.state.InputAmount)
  }

  Bet(){
    const contract = require('truffle-contract');
    const Betting = contract(BettingContract);
    Betting.setProvider(this.state.web3.currentProvider);
    var BettingInstance;
    this.state.web3.eth.getAccounts((error, accounts) => {
        Betting.deployed().then((instance) => {
          BettingInstance = instance
        }).then((result) => {
          // Get the value from the contract to prove it worked.
          return BettingInstance.bet(1, {from: accounts[0],
          value: this.state.InputAmount})
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.log("Error with betting",err)
        })
      })
  }

  MakeWin(){
    const contract = require('truffle-contract');
    const Betting = contract(BettingContract);
    Betting.setProvider(this.state.web3.currentProvider);
    var BettingInstance;
    this.state.web3.eth.getAccounts((error, accounts) => {
        Betting.deployed().then((instance) => {
          BettingInstance = instance
        }).then((result) => {
          return BettingInstance.distributePrizes(1, {from: accounts[0]})
        }).catch(() => {
          console.log("Error with distributing prizes")
        })
      })
  }




  render(){
        return(
          <div>
            <h3>Team A</h3>
            <h4> Total amount : {this.state.Amount} ETH</h4>
            <hr/>
            <h5> Enter an amount to bet</h5>
            <div className="input-group">
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" onChange={this.handleInputChange} required pattern="[0-9]*[.,][0-9]*"/>
                    <span className="input-group-addon">ETH</span>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <button onClick={this.Bet}>Bet</button>
            <br/>
            <hr/>
            <button onClick={this.MakeWin}> Make this team win</button>
          </div>
        )

    }



}

export default TeamA;
```

**Lastly my team b component**

```
import React from 'react';
// import {Grid,Row,Col} from 'react-bootstrap';
import getWeb3 from './utils/getWeb3.js';
import BettingContract from './contracts/Betting.json'
import './App.css';



class TeamB extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
      web3: '',
      Amount: '',
      InputAmount: '',
      weiConversion : 1000000000000000000
    }

    this.getAmount = this.getAmount.bind(this);
    this.Bet = this.Bet.bind(this);
    this.MakeWin = this.MakeWin.bind(this);
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    getWeb3.then(results => {
      /*After getting web3, we save the informations of the web3 user by
      editing the state variables of the component */
      results.web3.eth.getAccounts( (error,acc) => {
        //this.setState is used to edit the state variables
        this.setState({
          web3: results.web3
        })
      });
      return results.web3
    }).then(results => {
      this.getAmount(results)
    }).catch( () => {
      //If no web3 provider was found, log it in the console
      console.log('Error finding web3.')
    })
  }



  getAmount(web3){
    //Get the contract
    const contract = require('truffle-contract');
    const Betting = contract(BettingContract);
    Betting.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);
    var BettingInstance;
    web3.eth.getAccounts((error, accounts) => {
    Betting.deployed().then((instance) => {

      //Instanciate the contract in a promise
      BettingInstance = instance

    }).then((result) => {
      //Calling the AmountOne function of the smart-contract
      return BettingInstance.AmountTwo.call({from: accounts[0]})
    }).then((result) => {
      //Then the value returned is stored in the Amount state var.
      //Divided by 10000 to convert in ether.
      
      this.setState({
        Amount : result.words[0] / 10000
      })
    });
  })
  }

  handleInputChange(e) {
    this.setState({InputAmount: e.target.value*this.state.weiConversion});
  }

  Bet(){
    const contract = require('truffle-contract');
    const Betting = contract(BettingContract);
    Betting.setProvider(this.state.web3.currentProvider);
    var BettingInstance;
    this.state.web3.eth.getAccounts((error, accounts) => {
        Betting.deployed().then((instance) => {
          BettingInstance = instance
        }).then((result) => {
          // Get the value from the contract to prove it worked.
          return BettingInstance.bet(2, {from: accounts[0],
          value: this.state.InputAmount})
        }).catch(() => {
          console.log("Error with betting")
        })
      })
  }

  MakeWin(){
    const contract = require('truffle-contract');
    const Betting = contract(BettingContract);
    Betting.setProvider(this.state.web3.currentProvider);
    var BettingInstance;
    this.state.web3.eth.getAccounts((error, accounts) => {
        Betting.deployed().then((instance) => {
          BettingInstance = instance
        }).then((result) => {
          return BettingInstance.distributePrizes(2, {from: accounts[0]})
        }).catch(() => {
          console.log("Error with distributing prizes")
        })
      })
  }




  render(){
        return(
          <div>
            <h3>Team B</h3>
            <h4> Total amount : {this.state.Amount} ETH</h4>
            <hr/>
            <h5> Enter an amount to bet</h5>
            <div className="input-group">
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" onChange={this.handleInputChange} required pattern="[0-9]*[.,][0-9]*"/>
                    <span className="input-group-addon">ETH</span>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <button onClick={this.Bet}>Bet</button>
            <br/>
            <hr/>
            <button onClick={this.MakeWin}> Make this team win</button>
          </div>
        )

    }



}

export default TeamB;
```

I am sorry for posting such a length question as I am literally clueless at this point and don't know in which direction should I go.

Comment: Consider your private key as leaked and NEVER use it again

Comment: And add some reason string in your require, it should help debugging such -> require(condition, "the error is...") + check the console output of your browser (F12) -> is the provider succesfully injected?

Comment: yes web3 is successfully injected also the private key is random but thank you for information also I am not using ropsten anyways

Comment: Hi MohammadFahad! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! Try to narrow down the line that causes the problem to a solidity call first. Start by adding logs to lines surrounding possible places, log details like parameters. When you have the solidity call that is failing udpate the question with the details.